# Wordpress wpmember plugin payment method with Infusionsoft payment gateway

Tags: wordpress, infusionsoft

Is it possible to use wpmember (http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-members/) plugin integrate payment method using Infusionsoft payment gateway?

How to use Infusionsoft payment gateway in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various plugins you can use with wordpress such as [iMember360](http://imember360.com/features/). This will give access to users who have purchased from you in Infusionsoft.

If you are looking to charge users on your wordpress site instead of using the infusionsoft shopping cart you can try [Payment Gateway for WooCommerce](http://marketplace.infusionsoft.com/app/payment-gateway-woocommerce)

If you are interested in programming it yourself you can use the [Order Service](http://help.infusionsoft.com/api-docs/orderservice#placeOrder) to create an order in PHP from a custom module/plugin you create.

Answer (score 1):

[InfusedWoo](http://woo.infusedaddons.com/) supports using the Infusionsoft payment gateway with WooCommerce. Works great.

[WP Fusion](https://wpfusionplugin.com/) is another option for creating a membership site and making WordPress aware of your contacts. I've helped clients with iMember360 and WP Fusion and much prefer the latter.